# When I add a CALayer I to a custom UIView I hide a child UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I have a custom `UIView` with an `UIImage` inside. To that custom `UIView` I will add a gradient layer:

```
- (void)changeBackgroundWithLayer:(CALayer*)newLayer
{
    if (_gradientBackground != nil)
        [_gradientBackground removeFromSuperlayer];

    _gradientBackground = newLayer;
    [self.layer addSublayer:_gradientBackground];
}
```

But, when I do that, I can't see the `UIImage`.

**How can I do it to add the `CALayer` to the `UIView` and see the `UIImageView`?**

Hierarchy is:

```
UIView
  |
  ---- UIImageView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing as to what your view hierarchy actually is.

You say a `UIImage` in a `UIView`, do you mean you have a `UIImageView` inside a `UIView`? Or are you overriding drawRect to draw the image manually?

I would look at `insertLayer:atIndex:` as you need to make sure your gradient is behind the image layer. If you are drawing it manually, I would probably switch to a `UIImageView` add it as a subview to your `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
- (void)changeBackgroundWithLayer:(CALayer*)newLayer
{
    if (_gradientBackground != nil)
        [_gradientBackground removeFromSuperlayer];

    _gradientBackground = newLayer;
    [self.layer insertSublayer:newLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly same situation as me!